Proveedor de identidad con spring security en Azure AD B2C
estoy realizando una integración de Azure AD B2C con un servicio creado con spring security, este servicio realiza la función de proveedor de identidad para Azure AD B2C tal cual lo sería federar la autenticación con Github o Gmail.
He configurado el servicio para aceptar las solicitudes desde AD B2C, registrando la URL de inicio y la URL de respuesta de la respuesta con el siguiente formato:
URL de inicio: https://.b2clogin.com
URL de respuesta:  https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
También he creado un clientID y un secret en el servicio de spring security para aceptar llamadas de AD B2C, estos mismos datos los coloco cuando registro a mi servicio spring con proveedor de identidad en AD B2C.
Servicio spring:
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("clientIDpcori")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("https://<tenantb2c>.b2clogin.com")
                .redirectUri("https://<tenantb2c>.b2clogin.com/<tenantb2c>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/logout")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

Al momento de la integración AD B2C dirige la consulta de identidad al servicio spring, ingreso el usuario que definí, pero veo que cuando se intenta la llamada a la url de respuesta en B2C https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp, se obtiene un

código 400

Por favor si pudieran comentar si han tenido alguna experiencia integrando este tipo de servicios. Gracias de antemano.
Actualización:
He verificado que estoy obteniendo un error 401 cuando consulto la aplicación.
En la siguiente figura se muestra la interacción que se está teniendo con el servicio de identidad generado con spring security.

Al parecer este error 401 es por el secret que se envía cuando se hace el request para obtener el token, sin embargo me aseguré de setear el clientId y secret de forma correcta en AD B2C, a pesar de eso se mantiene el error.

Actualización 2:
Encontré el siguiente error en los logs:
2024-08-21T22:16:29.512Z TRACE 120 --- [auth-server] [http-nio-80-exec-1] o.s.a.w.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter : Client authentication failed: [invalid_client] Client authentication failed: authentication_method

He probado desde postman el servicio y funciona correctamente, no encuentro porque AD B2C envía mal las credenciales.

Se solucionó el error cambiando la siguiente linea en el codigo del proveedor de identidad
.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)

por
.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)

el metodo de autenticación debe estar como CLIENT_SECRET_POST
